# How does $\mathrm{ord}(a, p)$ relate to $\mathrm{ord}(a, p^n)$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, congruences

I may have the notation wrong, or in a nonstandard way; so here I am assuming $a$, $p$, and $n$ are positive integers, $p$ is prime, and $\gcd(a, p)=1$.

Then by $\mathrm{ord}(a, p^n)$ I mean the order of $a$ in the group $\mathbb Z/p^n\mathbb Z^\times$, which is the least positive exponent $k$ where $a^k\equiv 1$, modulo $p^n$.

Based on really simple examples I had noticed that in general $\mathrm{ord}(a, p)$ may not be $p-1$, even if $a$ is prime. However, in the examples I tried, if $a$ is prime, then $\mathrm{ord}(a, p^{n+1})=p^n \cdot \mathrm{ord}(a, p)$.

Is this actually true in general?

NB: This requires the condition that $a$ is prime. As remarked in the comments, this is not true if $a$ is not prime (although there are weaker theorems that can be proven).

NB2: This is not a question about primitive roots. We do not assume $a$ is a primitive root mod $p^n$.

Comment: See my answer here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1832701/question-about-primitive-roots-of-p-and-p2

Comment: Also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/31679/if-g-is-a-primitive-root-of-p2-where-p-is-an-odd-prime-why-is-g-a-prim

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Question about primitive roots of p and $p^2$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1832701/question-about-primitive-roots-of-p-and-p2)

Comment: @labbhattacharjee Neither of those links address the special case when $a$ is prime. Are you subtly suggesting that extra hypothesis is not useful?

Comment: @DietrichBurde This is not about primitive roots, but about to what extent the order of a (mod p^n) is controlled by the order of a (mod p).

Comment: @RichardRast,   Why $a$ has to be prime?

Comment: @labbhattacharjee In the situation I'm working on, $a$ is always prime. I'm interested to see if this gives any extra power for predicting these orders (which is otherwise a computational barrier).